# Removing a lease that has giving mac from dhcpd.leases with python?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to remove a lease from dhcpd.lease with python according to its mac address.

This is a dhcpd.lease example

```
lease 10.14.53.253 {
  starts 3 2012/10/17 09:27:20;
  ends 4 2012/10/18 09:27:20;
  tstp 4 2012/10/18 09:27:20;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:23:18:62:31:5b;
} 
lease 10.14.53.252 {
  starts 3 2012/10/17 10:15:17;
  ends 4 2012/10/18 10:15:17;
  tstp 4 2012/10/18 10:15:17;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 70:71:bc:c8:46:3c;
  uid "\001pq\274\310F<";
}
```

Assume I am given '00:23:18:62:31:5b'. Then I should remove all line belong to this lease. After deletion, file should look like

```
lease 10.14.53.252 {
  starts 3 2012/10/17 10:15:17;
  ends 4 2012/10/18 10:15:17;
  tstp 4 2012/10/18 10:15:17;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 70:71:bc:c8:46:3c;
  uid "\001pq\274\310F<";
}
```

I am simple reading a file and put it a string but I have no idea what to do after that. I tried this regex but didn't work. It checked only first line of the file.

```
fh = open(DHCPFILE)
lines = fh.read()
fh.close()
m = re.match(r"(.*lease.*%s.*})" % mac ,lines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is *not* shaped like a regular expression nail, so please put that hammer down.

The correct tool would be to parse the contents into a python structure, filtering out the items you don't want, then writing out the remaining entries again.

[pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) would make the parsing job easy; the following is based on [an existing example](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/dhcpd_leases_parser.py/33450777/dhcpd_leases_parser.py):

```
from pyparsing import *

LBRACE,RBRACE,SEMI,QUOTE = map(Suppress,'{};"')
ipAddress = Combine(Word(nums) + ('.' + Word(nums))*3)
hexint = Word(hexnums,exact=2)
macAddress = Combine(hexint + (':'+hexint)*5)
hdwType = Word(alphanums)

yyyymmdd = Combine((Word(nums,exact=4)|Word(nums,exact=2))+
                    ('/'+Word(nums,exact=2))*2)
hhmmss = Combine(Word(nums,exact=2)+(':'+Word(nums,exact=2))*2)
dateRef = oneOf(list("0123456"))("weekday") + yyyymmdd("date") + \
                                                        hhmmss("time")

startsStmt = "starts" + dateRef + SEMI
endsStmt = "ends" + (dateRef | "never") + SEMI
tstpStmt = "tstp" + dateRef + SEMI
tsfpStmt = "tsfp" + dateRef + SEMI
hdwStmt = "hardware" + hdwType("type") + macAddress("mac") + SEMI
uidStmt = "uid" + QuotedString('"')("uid") + SEMI
bindingStmt = "binding" + Word(alphanums) + Word(alphanums) + SEMI

leaseStatement = startsStmt | endsStmt | tstpStmt | tsfpStmt | hdwStmt | \
                                                        uidStmt | bindingStmt
leaseDef = "lease" + ipAddress("ipaddress") + LBRACE + \
                            Dict(ZeroOrMore(Group(leaseStatement))) + RBRACE

input = open(DHCPLEASEFILE).read()
with open(OUTPUTFILE, 'w') as output:
    for lease, start, stop in leaseDef.scanString(input):
        if lease.hardware.mac != mac:
            output.write(input[start:stop])
```

The above code tersely defines the grammar of a `dhcp.leases` file, then uses `scanString()` to parse out each lease in the file. `scanString()` returns a sequence of matches, each consisting of a parse result and the start and end positions in the original string.

The parse result has a `.hardware.mac` attribute (you may want to catch `AttributeError` exceptions on that, in case no hardware statement was present in the input), making it easy to test for your MAC address to remove. If the MAC address doesn't match, we write the whole lease back to an output file, using the `start` and `stop` positions to get the original text for that lease (much easier than formatting the lease from the parsed information).