# Dhcpd lease matching by using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, dhcp

I want to match all dhcp leases that have given mac address.

I wrote this code

```
fh = open(leaseFile)
lines = fh.read()
fh.close()
regex = r"lease\s*[0-9\.]+\s*\{[^\{\}]*%s[^\{\}]*?\}" % mac #mac comes as parameter
m = re.findall(regex,lines,re.DOTALL)
```

This worked well if a lease don't contain '}' character. But if it does, my regex failed.
For example:

```
lease 10.14.53.253 {
  starts 3 2012/10/17 09:27:20;
  ends 4 2012/10/18 09:27:20;
  tstp 4 2012/10/18 09:27:20;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:23:18:62:31:5b;
  uid "\001\000\013OW}k";
}
```

I couldn't figure out how I handle this exception. Thanks for any advice...

**EDIT**

After research, I decided to use this regex with MULTILINE mode. It worked for all leases that I tried.

```
fh = open(leaseFile)
lines = fh.read()
fh.close()
regex = r"lease\s*[0-9\.]+\s*\{[^\{\}]*%s[\s\S]*?^\}" % mac #mac comes as parameter
m = re.findall(regex,lines,re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: See [Removing a lease that has giving mac from dhcpd.leases with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623593/13624313#13624313). Do not use regular expressions for this task, it's not a regular expression problem.

Comment: I know it. this question was also mine. But I couldn't use pyparsing.

Comment: I know it was your question. The problem is that DHCP leases are, like [HTML and XML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/100297), a difficult task to parse for regular expressions. You should not use regular expressions for this task. Use line-by-line reading if you have to, but a regexp is not going to solve this for you. Using a dedicated parser or pyparsing instead would be *much easier*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex = r'(lease\s*[0-9\.]+\s*\{[^\{\}]*%s[^\{\}]*(.*"[^\{\}]*\}|\}))' % mac #mac comes as parameter
m = re.findall(regex,lines)
```

This should do the trick.